# onScannerClosedWithResult(no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.Beacon)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I am trying to write a app which scans for beacons,
when I login to the app, it starts scanning but after some seconds it just crashes. if I turn off my bluetooth it works fine. this is the error I get:

```
  Process: com.noxel.apppaneladmintry2, PID: 11192
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.niloofar.showroom.BeaconsFragment.onScannerClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.niloofar.showroom.BeaconScannerFragment.onCancel(BeaconScannerFragment.java:56)
        at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1260)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:921)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:716)
```

and this is my code,

```
    package com.example.niloofar.showroom;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.UUID;

import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.Beacon;
import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.BeaconRegion;
import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.BeaconServiceConnection;
import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.Proximity;
import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.ServiceProxy;

public class drawermenu extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, BeaconServiceConnection.BeaconsListener, BeaconServiceConnection.RegionListener {
public ProfileFragment profileFragment;
    private static final String SCANNER_FRAGMENT = "scannerFragment";
    public static final String NRF_BEACON_SERVICE_URL = "market://details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.service";
    public static final String OPENED_FROM_LAUNCHER = "no.nordicsemi.android.nrfbeacon.extra.opened_from_launcher";
    public static final String EXTRA_OPEN_DFU = "no.nordicsemi.android.nrfbeacon.extra.open_dfu";
    public static final int BEACON_COMPANY_ID = 0x0059;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private boolean mServiceConnected;
    private boolean mFragmentResumed;
    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private BeaconAdapter mAdapter;
    private BeaconScannerFragment mScannerFragment;
    int minor;
    public Fragment fragment=null;

    public FragmentA fragmentA;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

            BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
// Device does not support Bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(this, "Device dows not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            } else {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }

            }

            mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //   final Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getAllRegions();
        bindService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //  startScanning();
        if (mFragmentResumed)
            return;

        mFragmentResumed = true;
        //  bindService();
        onAddOrEditRegion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //  stopScanning();

        if (!mFragmentResumed)
            return;

        mFragmentResumed = false;
        unbindService();
    }

    private BeaconServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new BeaconServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected() {
            try {
                mServiceConnected = true;

                final BeaconScannerFragment scannerFragment = mScannerFragment;
                if (scannerFragment != null) {
                    startRangingBeaconsInRegion(BEACON_COMPANY_ID, BeaconRegion.ANY_UUID, scannerFragment);
                } else {
                    //   final FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                    //  if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    // Start scan only if there is no any other fragment (Mona Lisa) open
                    startScanning();
                    //   }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected() {
            try {
                mServiceConnected = false;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    public void onAddOrEditRegion() {
//        if (!ensurePermission())
//            return;
        try {
            stopScanning();
            //    mScannerFragment=null;
            final BeaconScannerFragment fragment = mScannerFragment = new BeaconScannerFragment();
            fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), SCANNER_FRAGMENT);
            //    fragment.isHidden();
            mServiceConnection.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(BEACON_COMPANY_ID, BeaconRegion.ANY_UUID, fragment);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void startScanning() {
        try {
            if (mServiceConnected) {
                startScanning(mServiceConnection);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        try {
            if (mServiceConnected) {
                stopScanning(mServiceConnection);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void bindService() {
//        if (!ensurePermission())
//            return;
        try {
            final boolean success = ServiceProxy.bindService(this, mServiceConnection);
            if (!success) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.service_required_title).setMessage(R.string.service_required_message)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.service_required_store, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                                final Intent playIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(MainActivity.NRF_BEACON_SERVICE_URL));
                                startActivity(playIntent);
                            }
                        }).setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void unbindService() {
        try {
            if (mServiceConnected) {
                // Unbinding service will stop all active scanning listeners
                ServiceProxy.unbindService(this, mServiceConnection);
                mDatabaseHelper.resetSignalStrength();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void startScanning(final BeaconServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
        try {
            final Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getAllRegions();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(cursor.getString(2 /* UUID */));
                final int major = cursor.getInt(3 /* MAJOR */);
                final int minor = cursor.getInt(4 /* MINOR */);
                final int event = cursor.getInt(6 /* EVENT */);

                // We must start ranging for all beacons
                serviceConnection.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(BEACON_COMPANY_ID, uuid, major, minor, this);
                // And additionally start monitoring only for those with these two events set
                if (event == BeaconContract.EVENT_IN_RANGE || event == BeaconContract.EVENT_OUT_OF_RANGE)
                    serviceConnection.startMonitoringForRegion(BEACON_COMPANY_ID, uuid, major, minor, this);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stopScanning(final BeaconServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
        try {

            if (serviceConnection != null) {
                serviceConnection.stopMonitoringForRegion(this);
                serviceConnection.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(this);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconsInRegion(final Beacon[] beacons, final BeaconRegion region) {
        try {
            if (beacons.length > 0) {
                final Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.findRegion(region);
                try {
                    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        // Check and fire events
                        final int event = cursor.getInt(6 /* EVENT */);
                        for (final Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                            if (event == BeaconContract.EVENT_ON_TOUCH && Proximity.IMMEDIATE.equals(beacon.getProximity()) && Proximity.NEAR.equals(beacon.getPreviousProximity())) {
                                fireEvent(cursor);
                                break;
                            }
                            if (event == BeaconContract.EVENT_GET_NEAR && Proximity.NEAR.equals(beacon.getProximity()) && Proximity.FAR.equals(beacon.getPreviousProximity())) {
                                fireEvent(cursor);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Update signal strength in the database
                        float accuracy = 5;
                        for (final Beacon beacon : beacons)
                            if (Proximity.UNKNOWN != beacon.getProximity() && beacon.getAccuracy() < accuracy)
                                accuracy = beacon.getAccuracy();
                        accuracy = -20 * accuracy + 100;
                        mDatabaseHelper.updateRegionSignalStrength(cursor.getLong(0 /* _ID */), (int) accuracy);
                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                mAdapter.swapCursor(mDatabaseHelper.getAllRegions());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnterRegion(final BeaconRegion region) {
        try {
            final Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.findRegion(region);
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    final int event = cursor.getInt(6 /* EVENT */);
                    if (event == BeaconContract.EVENT_IN_RANGE) {
                        fireEvent(cursor);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitRegion(final BeaconRegion region) {
        try {
            final Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.findRegion(region);
            try {
                if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    final int event = cursor.getInt(6 /* EVENT */);
                    if (event == BeaconContract.EVENT_OUT_OF_RANGE) {
                        fireEvent(cursor);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void fireEvent(final Cursor cursor) {
        try {
            final boolean enabled = cursor.getInt(9 /* ENABLED */) == 1;
            if (!enabled)
                return;

            final int action = cursor.getInt(7 /* ACTION */);
            final String actionParam = cursor.getString(8 /* ACTION PARAM */);

            switch (action) {
                case BeaconContract.ACTION_MONA_LISA: {
                    stopScanning();
                    //    final DialogFragment dialog = new MonalisaFragment();
                    //   dialog.show(mParentFragment.getChildFragmentManager(), "JIRNG");
                    break;
                }
                case BeaconContract.ACTION_SILENT: {
                    stopScanning();
                    //    final DialogFragment dialog = new tarh();
                    //    dialog.show(mParentFragment.getChildFragmentManager(), "JIRING");
                    break;
                }
                case BeaconContract.ACTION_ALARM: {
                    stopScanning();
                    //  final DialogFragment dialog = new rest();
                    //  dialog.show(mParentFragment.getChildFragmentManager(), "Jiring");
                    break;
                }
                case BeaconContract.ACTION_URL: {
                    stopScanning();
                    try {
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(actionParam));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_application, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case BeaconContract.ACTION_APP: {
                    stopScanning();
                    try {
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.setPackage(actionParam);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_given_application, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case BeaconContract.ACTION_TASKER:
                    //   switch (TaskerIntent.testStatus(getActivity())) {
                    //      case OK:
                    //         final TaskerIntent i = new TaskerIntent(actionParam);
                    final BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent recIntent) {
                            //            if (recIntent.getBooleanExtra(TaskerIntent.EXTRA_SUCCESS_FLAG, false))
                            Toast.makeText(drawermenu.this, R.string.tasker_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawermenu.this.unregisterReceiver(this);
                        }
                    };
                    //     getActivity().registerReceiver(br, i.getCompletionFilter());
                    // Start the task
                    //     getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
                    break;
                //   case NotEnabled:
                //     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.tasker_disabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //   break;
                //    case AccessBlocked:
                //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.tasker_external_access_denided, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //    break;
                //    case NotInstalled:
                //    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.tasker_not_installed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.tasker_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            //  break;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void onEditRegion(final long id) {
//        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeaconsDetailsActivity.class);
//        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
//        intent.putExtra(BeaconsDetailsActivity.ID, id);
//        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onScannerClosedWithResult(final Beacon beacon) {
        try {
            mServiceConnection.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(mScannerFragment);
            mScannerFragment.dismiss();

            mScannerFragment = null;
            // final Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.findRegionByBeacon(beacon);

            minor = beacon.getMinor();

            Intent intenta = new Intent(drawermenu.this, FragmentA.class);
            switch (minor) {

                case 99:
                    //  startActivity(intenta);

                    popUp();
                    break;
                case 246:
//                    startActivity(intenta);
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "246", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    popUp();


                    break;
                case 63:
                    popUp();
                    break;
                case 104:
                    popUp();

                    break;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private void popUp()
    {

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(drawermenu.this,FragmentA.class);
                //   mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

                drawermenu.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                //   Splash.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onScannerClosed() {
        try {
            mServiceConnection.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(mScannerFragment);
            mScannerFragment = null;

            startScanning();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public DatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper() {
        return mDatabaseHelper;
    }




    private boolean ensureBleExists() {
        try {
            if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_ble, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isBleEnabled() {
        try {
            final BluetoothManager bm = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            final BluetoothAdapter ba = bm.getAdapter();
            return ba != null && ba.isEnabled();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void enableBle() {
        try {
            final Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage());

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }




    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_points) {
            fragment = new PointFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_coupons) {
            fragment = new CouponFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.appbar, fragment,fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is the code which error is referring to:

```
    package com.example.niloofar.showroom;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.Beacon;
import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.BeaconRegion;
import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.BeaconServiceConnection;
import no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.Proximity;

/**
 * Created by niloofar on 11/9/2016.
 */
public class BeaconScannerFragment extends DialogFragment implements BeaconServiceConnection.BeaconsListener {
//    public class BeaconScannerFragment extends DialogFragment implements BeaconServiceConnection.BeaconsListener {
    private boolean mCompleted;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCompleted = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconsInRegion(final Beacon[] beacons, final BeaconRegion region) {
        if (!mCompleted) {
            for (final Beacon beacon : beacons)
                if (Proximity.IMMEDIATE == beacon.getProximity()) {
                    mCompleted = true;

                    final BeaconsFragment parentFragment = (BeaconsFragment) getParentFragment();
                    parentFragment.onScannerClosedWithResult(beacon);
                    dismiss();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setView(R.layout.fragment_scan).create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);

        final BeaconsFragment targetFragment = (BeaconsFragment) getParentFragment();
        targetFragment.onScannerClosed();
    }}
```

does anyone know how my problem will be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is the place where your problem occurs:

```
                final BeaconsFragment parentFragment = (BeaconsFragment) getParentFragment();
                parentFragment.onScannerClosedWithResult(beacon);
```

You initialize `parentFragment`, but the `NullPointerException` is thrown when you try to call `onScannerClosedWithResult`. This means that `parentFragment` is `null`. To solve this, you have three options. The first option is to use `try`-`catch` where you handle the `NullPointerException`. The second option is to make sure that `getParentFragment` will never return `null`. The third option is to fail gracefully when `null` is returned:

```
                final BeaconsFragment parentFragment = (BeaconsFragment) getParentFragment();
                if (parentFragment == null) {
                    parentFragment.onScannerClosedWithResult(beacon);
                }
```